# Atualizar projeto ao executar Maven

Tags: java, maven

Eu tenho um projeto java com pilhas Maven. Eu alterei umas funções java e apliquei novamente o comando `mvn clean install` pelo prompt. Mas na hora de executar ele não atualiza o código, continua com a mesma função.

Já tentei limpando todo o projeto e iniciando novamente, não adianta ele continua pegando as funções antigas. Será que por uma questão de performance ele guarda os arquivos em outro diretório senão o do próprio projeto?

Comment: O maven utiliza apenas dois diretórios: o diretório do próprio projeto e o dos repositórios que é onde são guardadas as dependências baixadas e o jar do seu projeto ao usar o comando install. Está acontecendo também com outros projetos??

Comment: No diretório do projeto ele atualiza, mas na hora de executar o java não. Acho que seria um problema do java né? Ou ele estaria enviando a função antiga para a pilha war? Esse é meu primeiro projeto com java então não sei te dizer.

Comment: Coloque seu pom.xml no pastebin para eu dá uma olhada. Outra coisa, o war dentro da pasta target não está sendo atualizado??

Comment: É isso que pensei, o que fiz: deletei todas as pastas que maven gera, como a target por exemplo. Mas continuou a mesma coisa. Atualizei o java com o comando `javaws -uninstall` para resetar o cachê java, e nada....  vou ver se consigo postar o pom. Obrigado